# Create Azure databricks notebook from storage account

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-storage-account

We have python script stored in Azure storage account in blob. We want to deploy / create this python script (as notebook) in azure databricks cluster so later we can run Azure data factory pipeline and pipeline can execute notebook created/deployed in databricks.

We want to create / deploy this script  only one time as and when its available in blob.

I have tried to search over the web but couldn't find proper solution for this.

Is it possible to deploy/create notebook from storage account? if yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can import notebook into Databricks using the URL, but I expect that you won't make that notebook public.

Another solution would be to use a combination of `azcopy` tool with [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html) (`workspace` sub-command).  Something like this:

```
azcopy cp  "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/script.py" .
databricks workspace import -l PYTHON script.py '<location_on_databricks>'
```

You can also do it completely in notebook, combining the `dbutils.fs.cp` command with Databricks's [Workspace REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import), but that's could be more complicated as you need to get personal access token, base64 the notebook, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can use databricks API 2.0 to import python script in databricks cluster.

Here is the API definition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace#--import